# Can I deploy a datasource and it's corresponding driver using an ear?

Tags: java, jboss, glassfish, datasource, ear

I'm wondering if I can deploy a datasource (the *-ds.xml) and it's required jdbcrealm driver using an ear file to either glassfish or jboss? If so is it recommended or better to manually install them?

Answer (score 2):

You can do both, but I would re-commend you don't. -ds.xml files in most cases are environment depended. A test environment will have other passwords for instance then a production system. If the database type is every environment the same you can choice to deploy the libray within the ear, but take in account that multiple driver libs in multiple ears will cause a bigger memory footprint.

Comment: Great thank you! For completeness can you describe where to place the -dx.xml and jar if we wanted to deploy via the ear? I'm positive we will do it outside of the ear per your recommendation.

Comment: the ds file should be in the root of the ear and jar in the lib folder of the server

Comment: A small correction to @MarkBakker's comment: for JBoss 7.x, the JDBC jar should be in the deployments directory, not on the server's lib (which should not be touched).